# UIRefreshControl and tableFooterView = UIView()

Tags: ios, uitableview, footer, uirefreshcontrol, refresher

In my tableView I need to have  self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView() otherwise the table scrolls too far down. The problem is if I add this then my pull to refresh UIRefreshControl no longer works. Is there a way to have both?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you can't have both. Have you added the `UIRefreshControl` in the right way? 
Here's working code from a project of mine:

```
var pullToRefreshControl : UIRefreshControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.setFooterView()
        self.addPullToRefreshView()
    }

private func setFooterView() {

        let footerView = UIView()

        let footerLabel = UILabel()
        footerLabel.text = "Table Footer"
        footerLabel.sizeToFit()
        footerView.addSubview(footerLabel)

        self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
    }

private func addPullToRefreshView() {

        pullToRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        pullToRefreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull To Refresh")
        pullToRefreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

        self.tableView.addSubview(pullToRefreshControl!)
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this exact code in my project and it did not work. (I had to delete  -> UIVIew since there's no return). For some reason the footer is preventing all scrolling.

Comment: One little note that could make all the difference - set the tableview style as `Grouped` instead of Plain, either in InterfaceBuilder or by code.

Comment: Sorry. Solved it! I had   self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false  which caused the refreshed not to work

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score -1):

Make a Custom Control refresh control for This

Comment: I'm sorry could you explain further?